# Let $G$ be an accessible f.g. group, then can we bound the number of vertex orbits in a reduced $G$-tree with finite edge-stabilisers?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I'm currently working on understanding the accessibility results of Dunwoody [1] and Bestvina-Feighn [2]. Both of these papers seem to state different Dunwoody's accessibility result differently. In particular, we have the following definition.

> **Definition.** We say that a group $G$ is *accessible* if there is a $G$-tree $T$ such that the edge stabilisers of $T$ are finite and the vertex stabilisers have at most one end.

In [1], Dunwoody shows that all finitely-presented groups are accessible. In [2], the authors restate Dunwoody's result as the following.

> **Theorem.** *Let $G$ be a finitely-presented group. Then there exists a positive integer $\zeta(G)$ such that if $T$ is a reduced $G$-tree with finite edge stabilisers, then $T/G$ has at most $\zeta(G)$ vertices.*

By a reduced $G$-tree, we mean a minimal $G$-tree such that the vertex group of every vertex of valence two in $T/G$ properly contains the edge groups of the abutting edges.

I can see from the argument in [1] that one can deduce the above statement by carefully examining the argument used, however I cannot tell if this statement follows from accessibility in general. Precisely, my question is the following.

> **Question.** Let $G$ be a finitely-generated group, and suppose that $G$ is accessible. Is it true that there exists a positive integer $\zeta(G)$ such that if $T$ is a reduced $G$-tree with finite edge stabilisers, then $T/G$ has at most $\zeta(G)$ vertices?

The reason that I ask this is that in [3], Dunwoody seems to use the affirmative of the above question to prove that a certain finitely-generated group is inaccessible (unless I am misunderstanding this paper).

I'm feeling a little bit lost with these results right now, so any references/explanations would be appreciated.

**References**

1. Dunwoody, Martin J. "The accessibility of finitely presented groups." Inventiones mathematicae 81.3 (1985): 449-457.
2. Bestvina, Mladen, and Mark Feighn. "Bounding the complexity of simplicial group actions on trees." Inventiones mathematicae 103.1 (1991): 449-469.
3. Dunwoody, Martin J. "An inaccessible group." Geometric group theory 1 (1993): 75-78.

NB: I posted a similar question earlier today, but deleted it after realising my question wasn't quite formulated correctly.

Comment: The answer is no, just letting $\mathbf{Z}$ act on a linear tree by displacement $n$. Maybe you want to add another assumption ($G$ not virtually cyclic). Also $F_2$ acts minimally on the universal covering of a bouquet of two $n$-cycles.

Comment: @YCor Thanks, reading closely I have missed an extra assumption, namely we want reduced $G$-trees, not just minimal. I'll edit the question now to add this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be an accessible group. Fix a reduced decomposition $G= \pi_1(\mathbb{A})$ as a graph of groups whose edge-groups are finite.

**Step 1.** We begin by "blowing up" the vertex-groups of $\mathbb{A}$ that have more than one end, replacing them with reduced decompositions as graphs of groups with finite edge-groups and with vertex-groups that have at most one end. The construction is described in Dick and Dunwoody's book *Groups acting on graphs* (Section III.3). Thus, one obtains a new reduced decomposition $G=\pi_1(\mathbb{A}')$ where the number of vertices (resp. edges) of $\mathbb{A}'$ is at least the number of vertices (resp. edges) of $\mathbb{A}$.

Now, I want to simplify $\mathbb{A}'$. Namely, I want the graph of groups to satisfy: $(\ast)$ for every edge $[u,v]$, if $G_u = G_{[u,v]}$ then $u=v$. This condition is stronger than being reduced. Observe that, if $[u,v]$ is an edge with $G_u = G_{[u,v]}$ and $u \neq v$, then one can collapse this edge. So, after collapsing some edges, one obtains a new graph of groups $\mathbb{A}''$. Reversely, $\mathbb{A}'$ is obtained from $\mathbb{A}''$ by expanding edges. But, because $\mathbb{A}'$ is reduced, we have to avoid creating vertices of degree two. Typically, the picture is

[image]

As a consequence, the quantity $$\sum\limits_{v \text{ vertices}} \left( \mathrm{deg}(v)-1 \right)$$ decreases after each expansion. So
$$v(\mathbb{A}) \leq v(\mathbb{A}') \leq v(\mathbb{A}'')+ \sum\limits_{u \text{ vertex of } \mathbb{A}''} \left( \mathrm{deg}(u)-1 \right)= 2 e(\mathbb{A}'')$$
where $v(\cdot)$ and $e(\cdot)$ denote the number of vertices and edges under consideration.

Since $G$ surjects onto the fundamental group of the graph underlying $\mathbb{A}''$, which has rank $e(\mathbb{A}'')-v(\mathbb{A}'')$, we conclude that
$$v(\mathbb{A}) \leq 2 v(\mathbb{A}'') + 2\mathrm{rank}(G).$$
In the next step, we show that $v(\mathbb{A}'')$ depends only on $G$.

**Step 2.** In order to conclude the proof, we observe that:

> *Any two decompositions of $G$ as $(\ast)$-graphs of groups whose edge-groups are finite and whose vertex-groups have at most one end have the same number of vertices.*

So let $\mathbb{B}, \mathbb{C}$ be two such graphs of groups and let $\mathcal{B}$ (resp. $\mathcal{C}$) denote the collection of vertex-groups in $\mathbb{B}$ (resp. $\mathbb{C}$). We are going to prove that $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ have the same size.

Write $\mathcal{B}= \{B_1,\ldots, B_r\}$ and $\mathcal{C}= \{C_1,\ldots, C_s\}$. For every $1 \leq i \leq r$, there exist $g_i \in G$ and $1 \leq n(i) \leq s$ such that $B_i \leq g_i C_{n(i)}g_i^{-1}$; and similarly, for every $1 \leq i \leq s$, there exist $h_i \in G$ and $1 \leq m(i) \leq r$ such that $C_i \leq h_i B_{m(i)} h_i^{-1}$. Of course, we have
$$B_i \leq g_ih_{n(i)} B_{m(n(i))} h_{n(i)}^{-1}g_i^{-1} \text{ and } C_j \leq h_j g_{m(j)} C_{n(m(j))} g_{m(j)}^{-1}h_j^{-1}$$
for all $1 \leq i \leq r$ and $1 \leq j \leq s$. Now, apply the following lemma in order to conclude that $m(n(i))=i$ and $n(m(j))=j$, i.e. $m$ and $n$ are bijections.

**Lemma:** *Let $G$ be group that decomposes as a reduced graph of groups whose edge-groups are finite and whose vertex-groups have at most one end. Let $\mathcal{H}$ denote the set of vertex-groups. Then, for all $H,H' \in \mathcal{H}$ and $h \in H$, if $H \leq hH'h^{-1}$ then $H=H'$.*

Considering the action of $G$ on the Bass-Serre tree, $G_u$ and $hG_vh^{-1}$ stabilise two vertices $a$ and $b$. If $G_u \leq hG_vh^{-1}$, then $G_u$ stabilises the geodesic $[a,b]$, which implies that $G_u$ coincides with the stabiliser of each edge of $[a,b]$. By applying property $(\ast)$ step by step along the vertices in $[a,b]$, we conclude that $u=v$.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you! I'm having a bit of trouble with the last lemma, I think the notation $H$ is overloaded. Do you have a reference for this lemma in the literature at all?

Comment: I realised that I used a different notion of reduced graph of groups. So I rewrote my answer. Do not hesitate to ask for precisions if some arguments are not clear enough.

Comment: I think this answer is very clear, thank you. Out of curiosity, what definition of reduced g.o.g. did you consider originally?

Comment: Precisely the condition $(\ast)$ I use in my answer.